# Setting up a reminder which has no end date

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scheduler

I'm currently building "reminder" functionality into a larger system. I'm able to create reminders that have a specific number of occurrences, as well as reminders with a definitive end date. I essentially add a number of entries into a table, and this also allows them to check off the tasks as each item is completed.

However, if a user wants an reminder with an indefinite end date, what is the typical way of handling this? I assume entering in 50+ years worth of entries isn't particularly efficient, and if doing this strictly in code and parsing out the items one by one, I need to determine if past reminders were completed, and not show them again.

How does outlook handle this behind the scenes, or google calendar?

Comment: I'd probably opt for an EndDate of `null`

Comment: That's what I've done, but how do I pull those reminders out of the system effectively? It then needs to be calculated out somehow. I'm not sure if I should have a background process load the next 'x' days into the system nightly, or simply pull things out from the DB and parse in code.

Comment: add it in database with some EndDate value like 30 days from now and if that task don't get completed move it to forward to next 30 days then continue on

Comment: @Jonesopolis: Using `null` for arbitrary special cases is a terrible design decision. Having to special-case `null` is the cause of uncountable programming bugs. Just my opinion, shared by many.

Comment: ehh I agree in general, but I wouldn't call this an 'arbitrary special case'.  What's the end date? There isn't one.  Null makes sense from a database design perspective to me for this.

Comment: Seems like `DateTime.MaxValue` (or the SQL Server equivalent) would be a more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recurrence patterns.  Most scheduling systems do not store individual occurrences in a database.  iCal uses a format called RRule, which is pretty popular.  There is an iCal.Net library that can parse iCal RRules.

As for past reminders, that is what should be stored in the database.  Store occurrences that have been completed.

https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net

Comment: This looks great. I guess the only thing this leaves is to track which occurrences have been marked off as completed. Is this something that's commonly handled as well with some sort of utility?

Comment: When I had to write a scheduler recently I decided to store completed tasks as individual database rows.  The reason I did this is because the completed task has result data stored with it.

Comment: I suspect you would want to do the same.  What information you store would depend on your use case.  It may be enough to link a schedule ID and a date/time in a "completed" table. -- sorry for the double comment.

Comment: This is certainly what I'm thinking. It just feels like if a reminder for something daily comes up 5 years down the road, it may become sluggish.